# Can I classify graduated symbology ranges by current render extent?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a layer with population densities for tracts for an entire country and I want to graduate the symbology with a color ramp to show areas of relatively high or low population densities. The graduated symbology option that creates x classes by whatever mode (equal interval, equal count, etc.) looks great, but the problem is that some parts of the country are more densely populated than others, leading a misleading visualization when considering less densely populated areas.

Is there a way to set the symbology so that it dynamically reclassifies the layer symbology based on the current render extent? E.g. the maximum value for population density for the entire country is something like 10,000 persons/km2. So when rendering the entire country, it makes sense for the color ramp to scale with 10,000 persons/km2. But if I zoom to a town where the maximum tract population density is 1000 persons/km2, I want the darkest color to represent the local maximum.

Comment: Would you use this style only for working with the data, or for presentation?

Comment: Both, preferably. The presentation is more important though.

Comment: Then please refrain from using dynamic graduated symbols. It'd be bad cartographical practice and could/most likely will lead to confusion. Many people don't take the time to have a look at the legend again and again, thus the symbology should not change between parts of the same map. Best case is you get asked to change the symbology, worst case is decisions get made based on wrong data interpretation.

Comment: Full disclosure: I haven't quite figured out how to finish up the presentation, since I'm a bit of a newcomer to QGIS. But I envisioned something similar to this, where the presentation would not be a static image, but rather a dynamic application/service (not sure if I'm using these terms correctly): https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/07/08/us/census-race-map.html


Here you can see that the values of the dots change based on scale.